# Incorrect Syntax near ',', Expecting ID, QUOTED_ID, STRING, or TEXT_LEX

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

This is a file `schema.sql` that I am coding with SQLite on Flask. I get a syntax error message on comma next to autoincrement. I am wondering what is wrong with this.

```
drop table if exists entries;

create table entries 
(
    id     integer primary key autoincrement,
    title  text not null,
    'text' text not null
);
```

[This is image of schema.sql]

Actually, I do not know how to check errors for sql file since I just get started to learn sqlite through a tutorial "Flask".

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/schema/#tutorial-schema

This is the webpage where I am learning from.

I am using Vscode as my editor, and I saw the message when I hover my mouse cursor over the comma that has a red line on it.

Comment: Show the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your query in SQLite; the query itself seems to work just fine.

```
$ sqlite3 foo.sqlite
SQLite version 3.19.3 2017-06-27 16:48:08
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> drop table if exists entries;
sqlite> create table entries ( id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, 'text' text not null );
sqlite> .schema entries
CREATE TABLE entries ( id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, 'text' text not null );
sqlite> INSERT INTO entries (title, 'text') VALUES ('foo-title', 'foo-text');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM entries;
1|foo-title|foo-text
sqlite> ^D
$
```

Perhaps the error is elsewhere.